# Calculating the Maximum Volume of a Rectangular Parallelepiped Inscribable in an Ellipsoid

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, volume, lagrange-multiplier

I'm working on the following optimization problem and I need guidance to proceed:

**Step 1: Problem Definition**

I'm tasked with calculating the maximum volume of a rectangular parallelepiped with edges parallel to the coordinate axes that can be inscribed in the ellipsoid $2x^2 + 3y^2 + z^2 = 18$.

**Step 2: Initial Setup**

I initiated the problem by considering that the volume of the parallelepiped can be expressed as $V = 2xyz$, where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are the lengths of the edges of the parallelepiped.

Next, to ensure that the parallelepiped is inscribed in the ellipsoid, we need to ensure that all its corners are contained on the surface of the ellipsoid. This implies that the coordinates of the corners of the parallelepiped must satisfy the equation of the ellipsoid: $2x^2 + 3y^2 + z^2 = 18$.

**Step 3: Optimization Problem**

My goal is to maximize the volume $V$ subject to the constraint of the ellipsoid. This translates to the following optimization problem:

Maximize $V = 2xyz$

Subject to the constraint: $2x^2 + 3y^2 + z^2 = 18$

But here is where I get stuck and don't know how to proceed: I need assistance to continue and solve this optimization problem. What would be the appropriate approach to maximize the volume of the parallelepiped while satisfying the ellipsoid constraint? How can I formulate the relevant equations and find the maximum volume? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what is the Lagrange multiplier method?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this problem. Should I use the Lagrange Multiplier Method in the following way: $L(x,y,z,λ)=2xyz+λ(18−2 x^2−3 y^2−z^2)$?

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: To @Ayesca: That is one way how to tackle this optimization problem. Next, you may find here at MSE community a few similar posts/questions, and probably you will find there some other approaches...